# What is the fundamental difference between 'lok' and 'jagat'?

Tags: terminology, lokas, universe, meaning, nirukta

We generally refer **Jagat** to our physical universe. I think there is no ambiguity about it. Hence, Jagat is the same for all living beings living in the same physical universe with a *physical* body.

But, I think there is another word **lok**, which people mostly misinterpret. It may not be referring to the physical universe and may be referring to the worlds that are experienced by a conscious mind with its subtle body. We generally call swarga, Naraka, worlds in Swapna and several others lokas and not Jagaths as they are experienced by jivas personally and not by all of the people sharing the same physical universe. Note that the names of bodies may vary across lokas. For example `yatana deha` in naraka loka, `bhoga deha` in swarga loka etc.,

In some sense, If I am correct, Jagath is objective and lok is subjective. Like a person can record places of a Jagat and cannot record video of a loka from Jagat. Am I correct?

**What is the fundamental difference between Jagat and Lok? Please explain it with the help of niruktha if possible and with examples (of their usage) from scriptures.**

Although I wrote my interpretation above, I want to explain my understanding further. Suppose we all are living in this physical universe with physical bodies. So we call it Jagat. If a person is in a dream, it is Swapna loka for her. She may believe it as Jagat due to illusion, but it is still a loka. The people living with us in Jagat are entirely different from those in a dream (Swapna loka). All the people in that Swapna loka believe that it is Jagat for them. The same is the case with hell and heaven. So, these words entirely *depend on the frame of reference*. Suppose we fix our physical universe as Jagat, then all remaining worlds experienced by a jiva are lokas for us. An average person involuntarily shares Jagat with others and cannot share lokas with others. A yogi can also share lokas of others as she is capable of travelling across lokas.

Comment: Lokyate Anubhuyate iti Lokaha , HH Shankaras commentary -Ishavasya upanishad/asuryā nāma te lokā andhena tamasāvṛtāḥ |(verse 3 Ishavasya).you may choose to check Ishavasya Upanishad.